# Date and Time picker with disable future and past dates and times

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time, picker

I created this date and time picker but I have issue that is I want to make disable past dates and then enable future 15 days dates and time and again after 15 days future date and time will disabled. I am familiar with Jquery and Js. Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/techWorld/28f7hgus/1/)

I also research on google and stackoverflow and sitepoint community but I don't get any helpful answer for me if I get so.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" />

<!-- Here by using Id selector the datetime picker will load on this input element -->
<input id="datetimepicker" type="text">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.craig.is/js/rainbow-custom.min.js"></script>
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
         $.datetimepicker.setLocale('pt-BR');
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
      });
</script>
```

Comment: please provide your code

Comment: @ZarnaBorda I updated the thread with code, please help

Answer (score 1):

Use minDate and maxDate for disabling past and future dates.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var today = new Date();
    var newdate = new Date();
    newdate.setDate(today.getDate() + 15);
    var maxtime = new Date();
    maxtime.setMinutes(maxtime.getMinutes() + 30); // timestamp
    $.datetimepicker.setLocale('pt-BR');
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        minDate: today,
        minDateTime: today,
        maxDate: newdate,
        step: 30
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" />

<!-- Here by using Id selector the datetime picker will load on this input element -->
<input id="datetimepicker">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.craig.is/js/rainbow-custom.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
     var today = new Date();
      var newdate = new Date();
      newdate.setDate(today.getDate() + 15);
      var maxtime = new Date();
      maxtime.setMinutes(maxtime.getMinutes() + 30); // timestamp
      $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker.setLocale('pt-BR');
      $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
          minDate: today,
       minDateTime: today,
        maxDate: newdate,
        step: 30
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you but i think I mistaked to explain you what I want to say. `https://i.ibb.co/ftp35Dp/screenshot.png` please have short look this image ,I want disabled past time from now too sir, i dont want user click past time todays only they can click future times only. Please update the answer once more.

Comment: you want to disable from today date or from a selected date?

Comment: I want disable past time too sir.. user can able to select future time from half hours after. suppose now time is `10:00AM` so user can select time `10:30PM` in this time `30` minutes disabled.

Comment: try `minDate: today,` instead of `minDateTime: today,`

Comment: @ZarnaBorda recent updated `https://jsfiddle.net/techWorld/28f7hgus/4/` code is this everything is good but for fuiture time must enable after current time + 30min like in image pls see once `https://i.ibb.co/KFBNsfc/screenshot.png`

Comment: Remove maxDate from function. It will enable future time

Comment: @ZarnaBorda I try to do but it not works please `Collaborate` the js as mentioned in my last previous comment. Please disabled past times and enable futures time. sir. You help me last help me too.

Comment: use minDateTIme which disable past time and date also and use step:30 which shows the time which actully you want.

Comment: Please update sir.. `$(document).ready(function() {
     var today = new Date();
      var newdate = new Date();
      newdate.setDate(today.getDate() + 15);
      var maxtime = new Date();
      maxtime.setMinutes(maxtime.getMinutes() + 30); // timestamp
      $.datetimepicker.setLocale('EN');
      $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
     minDate: today,
        maxDate: newdate,
        step: 30,
        maxTime: maxtime.getTime()
      });
  });`

Comment: above your code there is past date is also enabled and today future time is disabled,,

Comment: everything is excellent but still past date is enable , I want disabled it..like past time,, how i change the formate of date in `DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss`

Comment: add minDate: today

Comment: Sir, I seen the bug there, When I select today date it show current time too with minute in textbox without my time click. I want if user click time it will show `+30 minutes` from now not current minutes.